# Binary search, when to use right = mid - 1, and when to use right = mid?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pointers, binary-search

I was working through this problem on leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/leftmost-column-with-at-least-a-one/ and I cant think of an intuitive answer.

Why is the right (or high) pointer sometimes set to mid - 1, and why is it sometimes correct to set to mid?

I am aware that we must always set left = mid + 1 because of integer division. When only two elements remain, we need to set mid + 1 to avoid an infinite loop.

But what are the cases to use right = mid - 1, vs right = mid?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary search Python Why do we use mid + 1 or mid - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256647/binary-search-python-why-do-we-use-mid-1-or-mid-1)

Comment: Not really. I’m interested in knowing when to apply mid - 1 vs just mid for the right value.

Comment: It only depends on your implementation of the loop and calculation of mid. There's no particular "correct way"

Comment: If function implementation uses **inclusive** right border, you should  `right = mid-1`, if not (like python ranges) -   `right = mid`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's say you are doing binary search on a sequence like below

```
.....0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ....
```

Your decision function `fn` returns `true` if the value holds `true` for `1`.

Now consider your target is to find the last position for `0`. In each step of binary search, we will reduce search space such that we are certain the position is within the range.
If `fn` returns `true` for `mid` you know that the last position for `0` will be less than mid (because you want the last occurrence of `0` which must be before the first occurrence of `1`). So, you will update `right=mid-1`. If `fn` return false `left=mid.`

Now consider your target is to find the first occurrence for `1`.
Now if `fn` returns `true` you will update `right=mid` because you know the first occurrence of `1` will be on this position or left of it. In this case, if `fn` returns `false`, you will need to update `left=mid+1`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!

Comment: adding on to this, is there any insight when to use terminating condition left < right, vs left <= right?

Comment: When you decrease the interval in both direction you can use left <= right i.e., left=mid+1 and right=mid-1. Else you need to use left<right, since, otherwise you will be trapped in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are three templates to implement binary search
**Template 1:  No depend on other elements and neighbor elements.**

```
while(left <= right){
    int mid = (int)Math.floor((left + right)/2);
    if(nums[mid] == target) return mid;
    else if(nums[mid] < target) {
        left = mid + 1;
    } else {
        right = mid - 1;
    }
}
```

**Template 2: Use when searching a value requires accessing the current index and its immediate right neighbor's index**

```
while(left < right){
   // Prevent (left + right) overflow
   int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
   if(nums[mid] == target){ return mid; }
   else if(nums[mid] < target) {
      left = mid + 1; }
   else {
      right = mid; }
}
```

**Template 3: Use when searching a value requires accessing the current index and both its immediate left and right neighbor's index**

```
 while (left + 1 < right){
    // Prevent (left + right) overflow
    int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
    if (nums[mid] == target) {
        return mid;
    } else if (nums[mid] < target) {
        left = mid;
    } else {
        right = mid;
    }
}
```

Source: [LeetCode Explore](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search)

Answer (score 0):

Linear search on a small array outperforms binary search. Thus it should not really matter if you are using or not using `-1`, because your search should break out when `right-left < N` and then you can do a linear search between the two (N is a parameter which you can find for your particular application by running a benchmark).

Iirc N for integer numbers was ~700 when I measured it last.